# Updating python dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have dictionary A:

```
{ 'name': 'Jack',
  'age': 24,
  'friends': ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Karen'],
}
```

and I have dictionary B:

```
{ 'name': 'Jack',
  'favorite_color': 'blue',
  'friends': ['Daren'],
}
```

How can I combine them so that the result only has fields that were in dictionary A and where the two have the same field update the value in A based on the value in B. And when the field is an array append to it instead of replacing it.

So the resulting dictionary C should be:

```
{ 'name': 'Jack',
  'age': 24,
  'friends': ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Karen', 'Daren'],
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the properties and perform the appropriate tests, steps... there is no built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = { 'name': 'Jack',
  'age': 24,
  'friends': ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Karen'],
}

b = { 'name': 'Jack',
  'favorite_color': 'blue',
  'friends': ['Daren'],
}

for key in a.keys():
    if key in b:
        if hasattr(a[key], 'extend'):
            a[key].extend(b[key])
        else:
            a[key] = b[key]

print a
```

Output:

```
{'age': 24, 'friends': ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Karen', 'Daren'], 'name': 'Jack'}
```

This assumes that if the field in `a` is a list, then the same field in `b` is also a list. In other words, if `b['friends']` is not a list, it could break. If that is a problem, you will need to check the type of the field in both dictionaries and tailor the behaviour accordingly.